# Mongoose programatically update single array property item

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a single array property item using mongoose:

```
const updatePurchaseItem = async (purchaseOrder, itemIndex, product) => {

    let position = "items." + itemIndex + ".product_id";
    let query = {
            _id: purchaseOrder._id,
            deletedAt: null
    };

    await PurchaseOrderModel.update(query, position: product._id);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "items.1.product_id" at path "_id" for model "PurchaseOrder"
```

What is the code proper syntax to make this work?

What does `path "_id"` means ?

Both `purchaseOrder` and `product` are read from the database using `mongoose.findOne()`.

Comment: how your model looks like? what does `product_id` contain?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing the parameter as an object? As in `{position: product._id}`

Comment: The problem says that the input passed from `product._id` is not valid. You can validate this with code by running `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(product._id)`